# Where can I put this Javascript that references a field that hasn't been built yet?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a piece of JavaScript that clears out a label (well, it sets its innertext value).  The problem is, after I've clicked a button and the page posts back, the label doesn't exist when the Javascript launches.  So, I get an error:

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property
>   'innerText' of undefined or null reference

And the code in the debug window looks like this:

```
.
.
<body id="PageBody" bgcolor="lightgrey">

    <script type = "text/javascript">
        /* Stop, Clear and Pause the timer displayed under the pause buttons  */
        var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
            start = document.getElementById('start'),
            stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
            clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
            seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
            t;

        function add() {
            seconds++;
            if (seconds >= 60) {
                seconds = 0;
                minutes++;
                if (minutes >= 60) {
                    minutes = 0;
                    hours++;
                }
            }

            document.getElementById('Call_Tab_TabPanelCall_h1').innerText = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);;
            timer();
        }

        function timer() {
            t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
        }

        function stp() {
            clearTimeout(t);
        }

        function clr() {
            document.getElementById('Call_Tab_TabPanelCall_h1').innerText = "00:00:00";   
            seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;   
        }
    </script>

    <form method="post" action="./MedIntakeMain.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="ctl02_HiddenField" id="ctl02_HiddenField" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="Call_Tab_ClientState" id="Call_Tab_ClientState" value="{&quot;ActiveTabIndex&quot;:0,&quot;TabEnabledState&quot;:[true,true],&quot;TabWasLoadedOnceState&quot;:[true,false]}" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=pynGkmcFUV13He1Qd6_TZKuxqzo1qNK0jLS5vOjXgYcG0yOhGAUyRMkYR1c88uLjzDmFYO_wTSY6btwoEa6chQ2&amp;t=635803038500000000" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
stp();clr();timer();//]]>
</
```

It just stops right at the `</`, which I guess is where the HTML would start?  It's that first line in function clr that gets highlighted.  If I comment out the 2 lines in function clr, everything works fine.

These functions are called using this asp on the front end:

```
<asp:Button ID="CallStart_Btn" runat="server" AccessKey="S" OnClick="CallStart_Btn_Click" Text="S̲tart" Width="112px" OnClientClick="this.disabled=true; stp(); clr(); timer();" UseSubmitBehavior="False" style="margin-left: 0px"/>
```

And then in the code-behind I've got 3 lines like this:

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel4, this.GetType(), "stopscript", "stp();", true);
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel4, this.GetType(), "clearscript", "clr();", true);
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel4, this.GetType(), "timerscript", "timer();", true);
```

So, where can I put that JavaScript so it will get called *after* the label exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
```

instead of

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock
```

This will put function calls at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things at play.

You could disable/hide the button until after the label has been created (presuming some user action causes the label to appear, it could also cause the button to enable/appear).

You could add a check to each function to ensure the element exists. Something like:

```
function clr() {
    var label = document.getElementById('Call_Tab_TabPanelCall_h1');
    if(label){
        label.innerText = "00:00:00";   
    }
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;   
}
```